# Break first loop and continue next loop if true

Tags: php, loops, foreach, break, continue

I have a `foreach` loop inside another `foreach` loop as this code:

```
foreach($array1 as $uid => $somevalues) {

  $status = true;
  foreach($somevalues as $somevalue)
    if(!isset($somevalue->$someothervalue))
      $status = false;

  if($status) {
    $content .= "some content added";
    $count++;
  }
}
```

**How it works**

As you see I am looping through all entries in `$array1`. For each entry I loop through the contained `$somevalues` array to look for a certain condition (that `$someothervalue` exists there). Now, if this condition (that something `isset`) is not true then the `$status` changes to `false`.

Only if the `$status` is still true after all loops of the inner `foreach`, I wish some action to be made (some content added to a text string `$content` and a raised counter).

**The goal**

The arrays I'm working with can be quite large and I have been looking at the `break` and `continue` commands to try to skip unnecessary parts to improve the code and have the script running through fewer loops.

As you can see, if a loop from the inner `foreach` results in `$status=false` then we can stop it right there (no further loops here are necessary). The `break` is good for this to skip the rest of the `forearch` loops.

If this is the case then we can also skip the rest of the current outer loop from the outer `foreach`, since there will not be run any code now that `$status` is `false`. For this purpose the `continue` command would be useful to let us skip the rest of the current outer loop and go on to the next array row right away.

**The question**

I have been looking at the command lines `break 2` and `continue 2` e.g. that let you skip the current AND the outer loop (two steps up) with their respective results (either stopping the loop entirely or skipping the rest of current loop). They work as double break - as a "`break break`" - and as double continue - as a "`continue continue`" - respectively.

But here I need something like `break continue` instead, if you get my point. The first loop should `break`, the next should `continue`. I am trying to avoid reaching the `if` statement in the code if not necessary. The check is already made and it feels like doing an unnecessary double check.

I hope the question is clear. Is there a method for this purpose to double skip from within the inner `foreach` but with the effect of two different commands `break continue`?

Comment: The problem with that is that when you exit the inner loop you do not know why it stopped. Was it because you ran through the entire array or because you reached a break statement? Therefore you do have to make the second check outside the inner loop to figure out what action to take. I do now think that by using iterations you can reach the effect of a "break continue" as you stated.

Comment: Another approach would be using an external function to run the inner loop and simply return false when your value is not set. But functions may cost a little too much considering that you said your array contains several items and performance is paramount.

Comment: Thank you @Vinicius Barros. Yes, creating a function to catch the return is something I did not think of. But it might be too heavy compared to simply keeping the current `if` way, as you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flag" variables are mostly a code smell, and an indication that you actually should be using a function:

```
function all_valid($somevalues) {
    foreach($somevalues as $somevalue)
       if(!isset($somevalue->$someothervalue))
           return false;
    return true;
}


foreach($array1 as $uid => $somevalues) {
    if(all_valid($somevalues) {
        do stuff
```

If you're prepared to sacrifice readability for performance, then how about:

```
foreach($array1 as $uid => $somevalues) {

    foreach($somevalues as $somevalue)
        if(!isset($somevalue->$someothervalue))
            goto next; // I don't believe I wrote this

    $content .= "some content added";
    $count++;

    next:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `continue 2`, it will '`break`' out of the first loop and `continue` the outer loop.

```
foreach([1, 2, 3] as $i) {
    echo $i . PHP_EOL;

    foreach([4, 5, 6] as $ii) {
        continue 2;
    }

    echo 'this will never print' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will print:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $uid => $somevalues) {
   // Task of loop 1
   foreach($somevalues as $somevalue){
      // Task of loop 2
      if(!isset($somevalue->$someothervalue))
          {
            continue 2;
            break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: continue 2 defines, the loop will continue from the second level. Than defining that brake this loop. So after breaking the 2nd loop (1st level) it will go to 1st loop (2nd level) then continue will work as it is defined for 2nd level. and It works

Comment: Thanks, is not to be rude, but there are some things answers need in this site. [I recomend this reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)